# How to Create a Chat Bot in a Web Site by using AZURE Services?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework

For `Creating a Bot`, Everywhere it is `given login` to azure and Create a Bot but `Instead of Login` there, is there a way to Create it from a `Website` By just Passing the `Required Parameters` by Using `API` References ?

Comment: What do you mean by "given login to azure and Create a Bot"

Comment: However first you have to register you bot with Microsoft Bot Framework and there after you can use `DirectLine` API to integrate that into you web site.

Comment: "Everywhere it is given login to azure": what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways how to embed chatbot to a website.

1. Use [Botframework Webchat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) for web interface

   - Get cdn link or download webchat
   - Init chat using Direct Line Token (you can get it if you uze Azure Bot Service)

```html
 window.BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: 'DIRECT_LINE_SECRET' },
        user: { id: 'boost7' },
        bot: { id: 'boost7 demo bot' },
        resize: 'detect'
    }, document.getElementById("div_id"));
```

Bot should be hosted in Azure as Bot Service to start working. If it is then it should work.

2. Azure bot service has option to embed webchat to your web. You can find it in bot service channels

Comment: There are more than these 2 options (custom webchat with the help of DirectLine for example) and the 2nd one you mentioned is the same as the 1st one

Comment: it is completely 2 different ways how to integrate webchat. I know only these 2. if you know more. tell us.

Comment: Can you detail your 2nd option?

Comment: First you need to open Azure->Bot Service (name) -> Channels -> Get bot embed codes. Then you will be prompted to configure keys, secrets and site name and will be able to copy iframe like... <iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/boost7botdemo?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE'></iframe>

Comment: So in fact exactly what is detailed in the wiki of the 1st version (Webchat): https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#easiest-in-any-website-iframe-the-standard-web-chat-channel

Hence my question about the difference: your 2nd item is also MS Bot Framework Webchat :)

Answer (score 0):

> For Creating a Bot, Everywhere it is given login to azure and Create a Bot but Instead of Login there, is there a way to Create it from a Website By just Passing the Required Parameters by Using API References ?

If you’d like to programmatically create **BotService** instead of login to Azure portal and create it on portal manually, you can try to use ***[Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager)*** with [ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-create-first-template) to achieve it.  The following code for deploying resource is for your reference.

**DeploymentHelper.cs:**

```
// Requires the following Azure NuGet packages and related dependencies:
// package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Authorization" version="2.0.0"
// package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager" version="1.4.0-preview"
// package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.2.8-preview"

using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Models;
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace PortalGenerated
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is a helper class for deploying an Azure Resource Manager template
    /// More info about template deployments can be found here https://go.microsoft.com/fwLink/?LinkID=733371
    /// </summary>
    class DeploymentHelper
    {
        string subscriptionId = "your-subscription-id";
        string clientId = "your-service-principal-clientId";
        string clientSecret = "your-service-principal-client-secret";
        string resourceGroupName = "resource-group-name";
        string deploymentName = "deployment-name";
        string resourceGroupLocation = "resource-group-location"; // must be specified for creating a new resource group
        string pathToTemplateFile = "path-to-template.json-on-disk";
        string pathToParameterFile = "path-to-parameters.json-on-disk";
        string tenantId = "tenant-id";

        public async void Run()
        {
            // Try to obtain the service credentials
            var serviceCreds = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

            // Read the template and parameter file contents
            JObject templateFileContents = GetJsonFileContents(pathToTemplateFile);
            JObject parameterFileContents = GetJsonFileContents(pathToParameterFile);

            // Create the resource manager client
            var resourceManagementClient = new ResourceManagementClient(serviceCreds);
            resourceManagementClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

            // Create or check that resource group exists
            EnsureResourceGroupExists(resourceManagementClient, resourceGroupName, resourceGroupLocation);

            // Start a deployment
            DeployTemplate(resourceManagementClient, resourceGroupName, deploymentName, templateFileContents, parameterFileContents);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads a JSON file from the specified path
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pathToJson">The full path to the JSON file</param>
        /// <returns>The JSON file contents</returns>
        private JObject GetJsonFileContents(string pathToJson)
        {
            JObject templatefileContent = new JObject();
            using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(pathToJson))
            {
                using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
                {
                    templatefileContent = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
                    return templatefileContent;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ensures that a resource group with the specified name exists. If it does not, will attempt to create one.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="resourceManagementClient">The resource manager client.</param>
        /// <param name="resourceGroupName">The name of the resource group.</param>
        /// <param name="resourceGroupLocation">The resource group location. Required when creating a new resource group.</param>
        private static void EnsureResourceGroupExists(ResourceManagementClient resourceManagementClient, string resourceGroupName, string resourceGroupLocation)
        {
            if (resourceManagementClient.ResourceGroups.CheckExistence(resourceGroupName) != true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Creating resource group '{0}' in location '{1}'", resourceGroupName, resourceGroupLocation));
                var resourceGroup = new ResourceGroup();
                resourceGroup.Location = resourceGroupLocation;
                resourceManagementClient.ResourceGroups.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, resourceGroup);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Using existing resource group '{0}'", resourceGroupName));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts a template deployment.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="resourceManagementClient">The resource manager client.</param>
        /// <param name="resourceGroupName">The name of the resource group.</param>
        /// <param name="deploymentName">The name of the deployment.</param>
        /// <param name="templateFileContents">The template file contents.</param>
        /// <param name="parameterFileContents">The parameter file contents.</param>
        private static void DeployTemplate(ResourceManagementClient resourceManagementClient, string resourceGroupName, string deploymentName, JObject templateFileContents, JObject parameterFileContents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Starting template deployment '{0}' in resource group '{1}'", deploymentName, resourceGroupName));
            var deployment = new Deployment();

            deployment.Properties = new DeploymentProperties
            {
                Mode = DeploymentMode.Incremental,
                Template = templateFileContents,
                Parameters = parameterFileContents["parameters"].ToObject<JObject>()
            };

            var deploymentResult = resourceManagementClient.Deployments.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, deploymentName, deployment);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Deployment status: {0}", deploymentResult.Properties.ProvisioningState));
        }
    }
}
```

Besides, to run above code, an Azure Active Directory (AD) application with right permissions is required, this article:"[create AD application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-active-directory-application)" show detailed steps, please refer to it.

**Note**: To quickly get template and code for deploying **BotService**, you can go Azure portal to create a new Bot Service and click **Automation options**.

[image]